# Using REST as Business Logic Layer ,Con and Pro

Tags: java, php, rest, jpa, jax-rs

[image: My Arch for a New Web Application]

I am thinking of creating an Application as i shown in the figure, i am creating the presentation layer in PHP, where JAX-RS REST Service is working as Business Layer and JPA as Data Object Layer
My Question is 
1)Is this arch secure?
2)Is this arch Scale?
3)IS there any other problem in my Arch?

Comment: 1: cant tell from diagram, 2: see 1, 3: see 2

Comment: @Gordon why??what all details you need??

Comment: well, basically *all* the details and not just some rough sketch diagram. Nothing of what you show is inherently more or less secure or scales particularly well or bad. In fact, even if you had provided a full fledged Software Architecture Document (which would then be closed as off-topic) we could only give general pointers. Whether your application is secure or scales or has any other problems depends a lot of on how it is implemented. A single slow query could harm your scalability. And a single unsanitized value might invite Bobby Tables to pay a visit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a quite generic question (e.g. like "I am going to by a car. 1) is it fast 2.) is it secure")

However, there are some things to say here:

1. The question is not, if the "architecture" is secure, but if you can
   make the services that you are using secure. If you are using e.g.
   Tomcat for the rest services, they will be as secure as you can make
   tomcat secure.
2. Since there is (or should be) no state in
   REST-services, this should scale well, provided you find the right
   granularity for your services and do not introduce artificial
   state-handling. If you attach a load-balancer in front of the
   REST-Services, each call could be sent to another machine (or
   process). This will most likely lead to the database being your
   bottleneck.
3. Yes and no. What you describe as architecture is very
   generic. Basically there is no problem in it if you do it right. But
   you can produce a lot of problems with it if you do it wrong.

Conclusion: Security and scale will depend on the details and the components you are using. Basically an architecture-type like the on you chose should provide a good basis for a scalable architecture (and implementation).

Comment: so u are saying there is no problem in my Arch? i can use it,right?So no Load Balance in front of REST-Service?? what else can i do to load balance??